# SKStoreProductViewController cancel button crash or not working

Tags: ios

I have implemented a delegate for the SKStoreProductViewController.
I add that view controller into the key window's view controller.
I have also implemented a dismiss view controller code in the delegate function.

The question seems to be answer in this question.
[Modal App Store won't dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935689/modal-app-store-wont-dismiss)

Yet, this problem still persist in my situation.

Display function

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    NSString *appURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/%@/app/id%@",
                        [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0], applicationID];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];

} else {
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:applicationID forKey:SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier];
    SKStoreProductViewController *viewCont = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    viewCont.delegate = self;
    [viewCont loadProductWithParameters:dict completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error)
    {
        UIViewController* viewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        if (viewController)
        { [viewController presentViewController:viewCont animated:YES completion:nil]; }
    }];
}
```

Delegate Function

```
- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController
{
    if (viewController)
    { [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you must implement

```
- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController
{
    if (viewController)
    { [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
}
```

inside the delegate class. If you implement it inside the class whose delegate is presenting the `SKStoreProductViewController`, it will not work because `SKStoreProductViewController` will try to call `productViewControllerDidFinish:` within it's delegate, which isn't implementing that method.

Let me show an example:

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)presentSecondViewController
{
     SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
     [secondViewController setDelegate:self];
     [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController
{
    if (viewController)
    { [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
}

@end


@implementation SecondViewController {
    id delegate <SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate>;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id)delegate
{
    _delegate = delegate;
}

- (void)callStoreProductViewController
{
    SKStoreProductViewController *viewCont = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    viewCont.delegate = _delegate;
    [viewCont loadProductWithParameters:dict completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error)
    {
        UIViewController* viewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        if (viewController)
            { [_delegate presentViewController:viewCont animated:YES completion:nil]; }
    }];
}
@end
```

So, if I did understand your problem well, you must implement `productViewControllerDidFinish:` inside your `viewController` class, as it is the one who is presentig the `SKStoreProductViewController`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please try in Delegate function, replace all lines with:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: self is not the view controller

Comment: Cancel button in SKStoreProductViewController or ...?

Comment: Cancel button in SKStoreProductViewController. But that class is not a view controller. The parent view is the key window's view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Where does this code reside? You set the delegate to the instance where this code is written, but you are adding the SKStoreProductViewController to the root view.
Have you tried adding the store to self?

```
[self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks for the delegate function.  It isn't obvious in the documentation.